# What is a good way to track changes in a staging DB and then push accepted data onto the main DB?

Tags: php, mysql

What is a good way to track changes in a staging DB and then push accepted data onto the main DB?

My client needs a script or any solution: if he has two database, one staging DB in which he tests his data on the test portal and if he find it appropriate he can use those changes on the main DB, which is displayed on the live site. For this he needs the solution to record or track all updates/deletes/inserts, so that he can do the same in main DB if found appropriate.

**NOTE:** we have only one server, no separate server, hence binary log replication doesn't seems to be working for my case.

Comment: Does the data in the live database end up the same as in the test database then? (or do they 'evolve independently' as Vlad Romanescu mentions)

Comment: the data in the live database end up the same as in the test database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that both test and production databases can evolve independently during the test period, I'd say a good starting point for thinking about a solution would be to activate query logging on the test database then, at the end of the day, extract `ALTER`, `CREATE`, `DROP`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` etc. statements from the test database query log file and simply try to play those statements back on the production database, possibly separating [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) and [DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language) (with the DML in one transaction.)

If any of your tables have auto-increment columns used as foreign keys in other tables, use an `AFTER` trigger to capture actual auto-increment values for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements and write a corresponding SQL statement to a separate file for production playback; you may still use query logging to capture DDL statements (and `DELETE`s, although they can be captured via trigger too.)

Unlike binary logs, query logs (or equivalent logs produced from a trigger) are clear-text and allow you to further manually tweak queries to resolve any potential conflicts or divergences between the production and test systems.

Comment: @Vlad I have created a trigger script tracj any change in any atable will be recorded in a separate  audit table, but as due to the Db structure, few tables do not have PK or any autioincremented field which i need to record in Audit table so that i can insert these values in my Main production DB, hence trigger concept is not working for me, and as far as log file is concerned, if it gets switched OFF/fluched due to memory then where will I find the changes?

Comment: CAn U put some more light on this issue @Vlad?

Comment: You should ensure (with those who connect to the system) that they do not disable logging (just like you'd have to ensure, in the case of the trigger solution, that they don't `DROP` your triggers) and that they will not remove log files if disk space goes down (just like you'd have to ensure, in the case of the trigger solution, that they don't `DROP` your audit table :) ).

Comment: Indeed, there will be a problem with query log playback if autoincrement PK values are then referred to as FKs in other tables.  In that case using `AFTER` (!) triggers will capture the autoincrement PK value (so go for that solution to track e.g. `INSERT`s), but you will still need query logging to capture DDL commands, if any are issued. :)